# Could anyone tell me why UIImage.ciimage is null

Tags: iphone, ios

I found that in IOS **UIImage** can change to **CIImage**.and there is a property CIImage in UIImage. and when i use the UIImage,UIImage object is not null but `UIImage.ciimage` is null ,why?

forgive my stupid question if someone can help me ,thank you very much.

---

ADD

for example, the code like below return null:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
CIImage *ciImage = image.CIImage
```

but if in this way CIImage is not null:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
CIImage *myImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:nil];
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is because this UIImage is not in fact a CIImage. In other words, UIImage's `CIImage` is not nil only if the UIImage is backed by a CIImage already (e.g. because it was generated by `imageWithCIImage:`). You can't use this to magically turn the UIImage into a CIImage, as you seem to be hoping to do.

The documentation is actually pretty clear on this. Always worth a read.

Comment: @matt How can you convert from UIImage to CIImage then?

Comment: @brimstone With CIImage's `initWithImage:` initializer.

Comment: I have found that sometimes going straight from CIImage to UIImage doesn't always work. I convert CIImage to CGIImage and then to UIImage and it works just fine.