# Passing a UIImage through a CIFilter produces a blank image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cifilter, ciimage

My app adds a filter to a selected image. The app works like this:

1. An image is selected from an image picker
2. The image is loaded as an ivar of my view controller
3. A button is pressed to add the filter to the image

When I press the button to add a filter, the main image view goes completely white. However, when I initially load the image from the picker, it shows up fine. Here's the code that adds the filter.

```
- (IBAction)addFilter:(id)sender {
    if(_imageToFilter)
    {
        CIImage *newImage = _imageToFilter.CIImage;
        CIFilter *myFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert" keysAndValues:@"inputImage",newImage, nil];
        CIImage *filteredImage = [myFilter outputImage];
        UIImage *outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filteredImage];
        [mainImage setImage:outputImage];

    }    
}
```

Comment: For those who are interested in this in the future here some code that invert colors of an image pixel by pixel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049313/how-do-i-load-and-edit-a-bitmap-file-at-the-pixel-level-in-swift-for-ios#24139701

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely with the CIImage *inputImage being assigned `nil`. Try using CIImage's `initWithImage:` instead of `_imageToFilter.CIImage` (more on the edits below):

```
-(IBAction)addFilter:(id)sender {
    if(_imageToFilter) {
      CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:_imageToFilter];
      CIFilter *myFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert" keysAndValues:@"inputImage",newImage, nil];
      CIImage *filteredImage = [myFilter outputImage];
      UIImage *outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filteredImage];
      [mainImage setImage:outputImage];
    }
}
```

Edit: per feedback from comments, the problem seems to be that `_imageToFilter.CIImage` returns `nil`. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/CIImage): "If the UIImage object was initialized using a CGImageRef, the value of the property is nil."

Using the CIImage initialization method initWithImage: initializes a CIImage object with a UIImage so it solves the problem. The rest of the code works fine, so I've returned it to the original filterWithName:keysAndValues: to stay focused on the problematic part. More re: the issue here: [Could anyone tell me why UIImage.ciimage is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651228/could-anyone-tell-me-why-uiimage-ciimage-is-null)

Thanks for the feedback and hope the answer helps the OP.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. I reproduced the issue and actually tested the code above before posting the answer.

Comment: Please explain why you think that merely using a different initializer plus a method should make a difference. Your code does the exact same thing as the one from the OP, only split into two method calls. Also, simply presenting code without explanation isn't a good way of answering (even if it would be correct).