# CIPhotoEffect CIFilters are ~invariant with respect to colour management. What gives CIPhotoEffect filters this property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, core-image, cifilter

To give this question some context (ho ho):

I am subclassing CIFilter under iOS for the purpose of creating some custom photo-effect filters. As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html), this means creating a "compound" filter that encapsulates one or more pre-existing CIFilters within the umbrella of my custom CIFilter subclass.

All well and good. No problems there. For the sake of example, let's say I encapsulate a single CIColorMatrix filter which has been preset with certain rgba input vectors.

When applying my custom filter (or indeed CIColorMatrix alone), I see radically different results when using a CIContext with colour management on versus off. I am creating my contexts as follows:

**Colour management on:**

```
CIContext * context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
```

**Colour management off:**

```
NSDictionary *options = @{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace:[NSNull null], kCIContextOutputColorSpace:[NSNull null]};
CIContext * context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:options];
```

Now, this is no great surprise. However, I have noticed that all of the pre-built CIPhotoEffect CIFilters, e.g. CIPhotoEffectInstant, are essentially invariant under those same two colour management conditions.

Can anyone lend any insight as to what gives them this property?  For example, do they themselves encapsulate particular CIFilters that may be applied with similar invariance?

My goal is to create some custom filters with the same property, without being limited to chaining only CIPhotoEffect filters.

--

Edit: Thanks to YuAo, I have assembled some working code examples which I post here to help others:

Programmatically generated CIColorCubeWithColorSpace CIFilter, invariant under different colour management schemes / working colour space:

```
    self.filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorCubeWithColorSpace"];
   [self.filter setDefaults];

    int cubeDimension = 2; // Must be power of 2, max 128
    int cubeDataSize = 4 * cubeDimension * cubeDimension * cubeDimension; // bytes
    float cubeDataBytes[8*4] = {
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
    };

    NSData *cubeData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cubeDataBytes length:cubeDataSize * sizeof(float)];

    [self.filter setValue:@(cubeDimension) forKey:@"inputCubeDimension"];
    [self.filter setValue:cubeData forKey:@"inputCubeData"];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
    [self.filter setValue:(__bridge id)colorSpace forKey:@"inputColorSpace"];
    [self.filter setValue:sourceImageCore forKey:@"inputImage"];

    CIImage *filteredImageCore = [self.filter outputImage];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

The docs state:

> To provide a CGColorSpaceRef object as the input parameter, cast it to type id. With the default color space (null), which is equivalent to kCGColorSpaceGenericRGBLinear, this filter’s effect is identical to that of CIColorCube.

I wanted to go further and be able to read in cubeData from a file. So-called Hald Colour Look-up Tables, or [Hald CLUT images](http://www.quelsolaar.com/technology/clut.html) may be used to defining a mapping from input colour to output colour.

With help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267567/how-to-use-lut-png-for-cicolorcube-filter) answer, I assembled the code to do this also, reposted here for convenience.

Hald CLUT image based CIColorCubeWithColorSpace CIFilter, invariant under different colour management schemes / working colour space:

Usage:

```
    NSData *cubeData = [self colorCubeDataFromLUT:@"LUTImage.png"];
    int cubeDimension = 64;

    [self.filter setValue:@(cubeDimension) forKey:@"inputCubeDimension"];
    [self.filter setValue:cubeData forKey:@"inputCubeData"];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB); // or whatever your image's colour space
    [self.filter setValue:(__bridge id)colorSpace forKey:@"inputColorSpace"];
    [self.filter setValue:sourceImageCore forKey:@"inputImage"];
```

Helper Methods (which use Accelerate Framework):

```
- (nullable NSData *) colorCubeDataFromLUT:(nonnull NSString *)name
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name inBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
    static const int kDimension = 64;

    if (!image) return nil;

    NSInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    NSInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
    NSInteger rowNum = height / kDimension;
    NSInteger columnNum = width / kDimension;

    if ((width % kDimension != 0) || (height % kDimension != 0) || (rowNum * columnNum != kDimension)) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid colorLUT %@",name);
        return nil;
    }

    float *bitmap = [self createRGBABitmapFromImage:image.CGImage];
    if (bitmap == NULL) return nil;

    // Convert bitmap data written in row,column order to cube data written in x:r, y:g, z:b representation where z varies > y varies > x.
    NSInteger size = kDimension * kDimension * kDimension * sizeof(float) * 4;
    float *data = malloc(size);
    int bitmapOffset = 0;
    int z = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row <  rowNum; row++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < kDimension; y++)
        {
            int tmp = z;
            for (int col = 0; col < columnNum; col++) {
                NSInteger dataOffset = (z * kDimension * kDimension + y * kDimension) * 4;

                const float divider = 255.0;
                vDSP_vsdiv(&bitmap[bitmapOffset], 1, &divider, &data[dataOffset], 1, kDimension * 4); // Vector scalar divide; single precision. Divides bitmap values by 255.0 and puts them in data, processes each column (kDimension * 4 values) at once.

                bitmapOffset += kDimension * 4; // shift bitmap offset to the next set of values, each values vector has (kDimension * 4) values.
                z++;
            }
            z = tmp;
        }
        z += columnNum;
    }

    free(bitmap);

    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:size freeWhenDone:YES];
}

- (float *)createRGBABitmapFromImage:(CGImageRef)image {
    CGContextRef context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    unsigned char *bitmap;
    NSInteger bitmapSize;
    NSInteger bytesPerRow;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    bytesPerRow   = (width * 4);
    bitmapSize     = (bytesPerRow * height);

    bitmap = malloc( bitmapSize );
    if (bitmap == NULL) return NULL;

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (colorSpace == NULL) {
        free(bitmap);
        return NULL;
    }

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmap,
                                     width,
                                     height,
                                     8,
                                     bytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    if (context == NULL) {
        free (bitmap);
        return NULL;
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    float *convertedBitmap = malloc(bitmapSize * sizeof(float));
    vDSP_vfltu8(bitmap, 1, convertedBitmap, 1, bitmapSize); // Converts an array of unsigned 8-bit integers to single-precision floating-point values.
    free(bitmap);

    return convertedBitmap;
}
```

One may create a Hald CLUT Image by obtaining an identity image (Google!) and then applying to it the same image processing chain applied to the image used for visualising the "look" in any image editing program. Just make sure you set the cubeDimension in the example code to the correct dimension for the LUT image. If the dimension, d, is the number of elements along one side of the 3D LUT cube, the Hald CLUT image width and height would be d*sqrt(d) pixels and the image would have d^3 total pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CIPhotoEffect` internally uses 
`CIColorCubeWithColorSpace` filter.

All the color cube data is stored within the `CoreImage.framework`.

You can find the simulator's `CoreImage.framework` here (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/`).

The color cube data is named with `scube` path extension. e.g. `CIPhotoEffectChrome.scube`

`CIColorCubeWithColorSpace` internally covert the color cube color values to match the working color space of the current core image context by using private methods:

`-[CIImage _imageByMatchingWorkingSpaceToColorSpace:];
-[CIImage _imageByMatchingColorSpaceToWorkingSpace:];`

Comment: Thank you YuAo, this was most helpful.  I am going to research the best way to create colour cube data.  I would like to write a tool that allows me to manipulate colours on a live image and then save out the "look" to the .scube format. I will then read that in my custom filter and apply it via CIColorCubeWithColorSpace.  Presumably I can just pass this method the CIContext's working colour space via the `context.workingColorSpace` property.

Comment: I edited my question with a followup - CIColorCubeWithColorSpace doesn't seem to give me the results I expected based on your answer, do you have any extra insight based on what I'm trying?  Thank you once again.

Comment: Hi,  Alexander.
The color cube data is a  multi-dimension array of colors. The `inputColorSpace` of `CIColorCubeWithColorSpace` is the color space the color cube data is in. You need to set the `inputColorSpace` based on your color cube data. Setting it to `context.workingColorSpace` is incorrect.

Comment: Hi YuAo, thank you for the clarification - that makes total sense, I don't know why I assumed any different!  It is now invariant.  Furthermore I have found and implemented code to read in the cubeData from a hald LUT image.  I will edit my answer with correct code etc.

Comment: I'm also trying to do what you're doing. However, using `CIColorCubeWithColorSpace` is not very memory efficient. Every color component in the color cube data is stored in a `float` value, which uses 4 times memory compares to storing the color component in a 8-bit `char` value. For example, if you have a 512x512 pixel color lookup table, the color lookup table itself will use 1MB memory, the color cube data will use 4MB memory.

Comment: Right, there are trade-offs.  Actually before I looked at this approach I wrote a separate tool that let me play with regular CIFilter chains and switch colour management on/off.  I would then find a look I liked with CM on and snapshot the filter settings, then switch CM off and readjust the settings until I had roughly the same "look" between the two pairs of settings.  Then in my custom filter I would just apply the setting presets based on whether the context was colour managed or not. The result was pseudo-invariant "looks" with minimal memory overhead (just extra work in defining them!).

Comment: Why you have to switch CM off? Even some builtin filters do not work well when CM is off.

Comment: For performance reasons, specific to the app I'm creating, I would like colour management to be able to be turned off if necessary. By default it is on for the reasons you state.

Comment: I wonder what they did for CIPhotoEffect.  Their .scube files are about 131 KB. Some have two files, but not all. These are the allowed dimensions along with image size and size in memory with float colour components.     `4: 8 x 8 px (1.02 KB)`
`9: 27 x 27 px (11.66 KB)`
`16: 64 x 64 px (65.54 KB)`
`25: 125 x 125 px (0.25 MB)`
`36: 216 x 216 px (0.75 MB)`
`49: 343 x 343 px (1.88 MB)`
`64: 512 x 512 px (4.19 MB)`
`81: 729 x 729 px (8.50 MB)`
`100: 1000 x 1000 px (16.00 MB)`
`121: 1331 x 1331 px (28.34 MB).`  I think I'll see how small one can go without compromising results.

Comment: http://www.quelsolaar.com/technology/clut.html says _Using a 4096 by 4096 identity CLUT, it will take up roughly 50 MB in a raw file format such as Targa. Compressed using ZIP, it will come down to 36 MB, but RAR compression will render a file size of only 124Kb. With the PNG file format you can also get drastic compression down to 131Kb. We strongly recommend the PNG file format if size is a factor._ So now those 131 KB .scube files are looking very much like 4096x4096 .png files, although I did try opening them as such to no avail.

Comment: scube file is actually a 32*32*32 color cube. So it takes up 32*32*32*4 = 131072 bytes.

Comment: I should not program so late :). That makes sense as I was comparing the memory usage of CIPhotoEffect with these other techniques, and of course they are more efficient than decompressing a 4k image into memory!  I am probably going to use hald images to define the looks and then pre-process them into color cube data as they do.

Comment: FYI, I have compared the visual results (by eye on 5k retina display) working with color cube data of different dimensions.  In my testing for typical photographic filters, results pretty much converge at level 25 - 36, which jives with Apple's use of 32x32x32 - a good trade-off between memory and visual fidelity.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how CIPhotoEffect/CIColorCubeWithColorSpace should work with color management on vs. off.

With color management ON here is what CI should do:

1. color match from input space to cube space.  If these two are equal this is a noop.
2. apply the color cube.
3. color match from cube space to the output space.  If these two are equal this is a noop.

With color management OFF here is what CI should do:

1. apply the color cube.