# The reason for converting an instance of CIImage into an instance of CGImage and only then into UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage, ciimage

I was reading an article about `Core Image` where I saw the following lines:

```
if let output = filter?.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
    let cgimgresult = context.createCGImage(output, fromRect: output.extent)
    let result = UIImage(CGImage: cgimgresult)
    imageView?.image = result
}
```

As you can see, the `CIImage` instance is first converted into a `CGImage` instance and only then into a `UIImage` one. After doing some research I found out that it had something to do with the scale of the image within the image view's bounds.

I wonder, is that the only reason (having the right scale for display purposes) why we need to do all those conversions because there is already an initializer for `UIImage` that takes an instance of `CIImage` as an argument?

Comment: Yes you can display a ciimage initialising an UIImage object but you won't be able to get a data representation of that image object (ie.: JPEG or PNG)

Answer (score 0):

In the [UIImage's reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624114-init) that wrote

> An initialized UIImage object. In Objective-C, this method returns nil if the ciImage parameter is nil.

and like @matt wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15651358/2776008)

> UIImage's CIImage is not nil only if the UIImage is backed by a CIImage already (e.g. because it was generated by `imageWithCIImage:`).

So, the direct init

```
UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
```

can be `nil`.

That's why we should be init the UIImage via the `CGImage`, not `CIImage`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the second quote is about the property `ciImage` on `UIImage` instance, not its initialization. And in the doc it is said that the initializer can return nil, but it is only in case of `Objective-C`. In its declaration for `Swift`, the `init` can't fail, so it can't return nil. As far as I understand, you are trying to say that the reason for converting into `CGImage` is that the return value for `UIImage(ciImage:)` can be nil. But as I mentioned above, in case of `Swift` it is a wrong assumption.